# Keeping terminal open when running a bash script from a desktop shortcut

Tags: java, bash, terminal

I am running a bash script from my desktop off of a shortcut I made for it. When I click on it it says "Execute in Terminal" which is the option I want to do. The bash script compiles and runs a java program I made and the point of the script is to handle the errors that the program may through through the compiling prosses to someone who has very little programming experience (not really important to the question though). When I launch it, it will open the terminal as expected. When it encounters the error it will print out the error to the screen as one would expect it to do but then will immediately close the terminal it opened.

What I want is for the terminal to stay open until someone exits the terminal so they can read the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to add a line of code at the end of your bash script with a **read** operation as follows:

```
read -p 'Hit ENTER to exit'
```

This will keep the terminal visible until you hit ENTER.